# Inputting Large Data into MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, bigdata

I am having a problem inputting large amounts of data into MongoDB (working with Python).

I have the data stored locally as a CSV file and am currently using:

```
call(["mongoimport", "-h", "mongo_address", "-d", "db_name", "-c", "col_name", "--type", "csv", "--file", file_name, "--headerline"])
```

However, the data is taking far, far too long to input.
Data size is about 50 columns * 12,000,000 rows
The Mongo progress bar lists over 2 billion tasks

> Progress: x / 2359887055 Y%

Is there a faster way to get my data into the db?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are IO bound... Buy more hardware? Do you need Python when looks like a shell script would work?

Comment: Unfortunately, buying more hardware isn't really an option :-(
If there isn't a way to make this work with my existing hardware, I'll probably have to change my entire strategy.

I'm using Python because I have multiple steps that need to be executed in order. The problem is that this specific step (CSV->Mongo) is taking too long.

Comment: I doubt you are going to find something faster than what `mongoimport` is doing, even if you wrote the whole import CSV and write to MongoDB code yourself. This is also entirely dependent on your actual hardware and possibly network specifications. If you have lots of data, then [you probably need a bigger boat](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=We%27re%20Gonna%20Need%20a%20Bigger%20Boat)

Comment: Currently, I'm pulling data from Hadoop -> PySpark -> CSV and then pushing from CSV -> Mongo. Might it be faster if I go straight from PySpark to Mongo? Or would I still encounter the same bottleneck..

Comment: Generally speaking, you might try multi threading and chunking up the csv file into x rows per thread

Comment: Pyspark to Mongo would do exactly what I just said... I think there's also other Hadoop Mongo connectors

Comment: There's also Pig, or Hive or Flume. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Skipping the CSV step would be a great idea.